# IntelliJ-IDEA видит ошибки

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, maven

Вышла проблема, что IDEA подсвечивает мне ошибки, но при запуске проекта он успешно запускается и работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую сборщик Maven, делал clean install, а так-же перезагружал проект, делал rebuild, а красным всё также подсвечивает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используете библиотеку `Lombok` и аннотацию `@Data`, тогда вам нужно установить в IDE плагин [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij)

Comment: Да, глупо с моей стороны второй раз натыкаться на одну и ту же ошибку. Спасибо за помощь